# Simplifying the code with same list comprehensions

Tags: python, parsing, hash-map

I have such method where:

- `primary_images` is `dict`,
- `additional` is `dict`,
- `get_uri_text` is some decorating method,
- `marker` is telling how to parse two dicts.

How can I simplify this method?

```
    @staticmethod
    def decorate_sort_images(primary_images, additional_images, get_uri_text, marker=False):
        srt_keys = sorted(primary_images.keys())
        new_result = OrderedDict()
        if not additional_images:
            #only primary
            for _key in srt_keys:
                new_result[_key] = [get_uri_text(iter_el) for iter_el in primary_images[_key]]
            return new_result
        for _key in srt_keys:
            new_result[_key] = [get_uri_text(iter_el) for iter_el in primary_images[_key]]
            if marker:
                if _key in additional_images:
                    new_result[_key] += [get_uri_text(iter_el) for iter_el in additional_images[_key]]
            else:
                new_result[_key] += [get_uri_text(iter_el) for iter_el in additional_images[_key]]
        return new_result
```

Comment: What do the dictionaries contain? What is the method supposed to be doing?

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the difference between the conditional branches is only whether or not to avoid `KeyError` occurring at `additional_images[_key]` when key does not exist. This code should have the same behavior:

```
@staticmethod
def decorate_sort_images(primary_images, additional_images, get_uri_text, marker=False):
    srt_keys = sorted(primary_images)
    new_result = OrderedDict()
    allow_key_error = additional_images and not marker
    for _key in srt_keys:
        new_result[_key] = [get_uri_text(iter_el) for iter_el in primary_images[_key]]
        if allow_key_error or _key in additional_images:
            new_result[_key] += [get_uri_text(iter_el) for iter_el in additional_images[_key]]
    return new_result
```

When `additional_images` is empty, `_key in additional_images` is always `False`, so we don't need the first `if` statement any more.

Note that I also removed a redundant `.keys()` from `sorted(primary_images)`.